# R. Create a column that is the min() value of my row

Tags: r, dplyr

For the following dataframe,

```
A    B     C    
1    2     3
```

how do I create a column that is the minimum of my rows so that my dataframe looks like this?

```
A    B     C    min
1    2     3     1
```

I've tried doing this, but it hasn't been working as it takes the minimum of the columns A, B, C, not of the row.

```
library(dplyr)
data_frame %>% mutate(minimum = min(A, B, C))
```

Comment: `df$minimum <- do.call(pmin, data_frame)`

Comment: you're amazing...